# Memory-mapped file misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, memory-mapped-files

According to [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) :

> Memory-mapped files enable programmers to work with extremely large
>   files because memory can be managed concurrently, and they allow
>   complete, random access to a file without the need for seeking

question  :

the whole principle of Memory Mappe File is to write/read bytes , and create views by location and offset.

What does it mean "NO need for seeking" ?

I **MUST**  know the start and the end ( offsets) in order to read a file.

So seeking DOES EXISTS !

I Do seek in this huge array of bytes....

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MMF has random-access, in contrast with a normal file where there is 1 specific point where reading or writing occurs.

Using offsets (and pointers etc) is not the same as seeking in a stream.

> I MUST know the start and the end ( offsets) in order to read a file

You don't 'read a file', you access memory and need address(es), not  a stream-position.

Comment: .1. This is not seeking disc wise, it means no seeking like in a stream. You can jump around in the file because you acces it as array.  STREAM you ahve to change positions  - that is a lot more clumsy programming wise.

Comment: If i have a 100 mb file of records ( Person classes). its impossible to access its middle content just like that. so i do have to start from the start and then read reciord by record until desired record. I cant just go in the middle of the array...?

Comment: How do you access the MMF? As a stream?

Comment: @HenkHolterman lets say i have a huge byte array , Im crating a view with start offset...

Answer (score 3):

When using memory mapped files you basically get a pointer to a block of memory and access it as an array of some type. Then accessing specific locations in the file is index and/or offset based access to memory. The OS manages the seeking needed invisibly behind.

Answer (score 1):

MMF are the files actually "mapped" to virtual memory space, so you can think of it like (very generalistic comparison) of Dictionary in regard of Array. It's comfortable (if not say only possible) solution  when dealing with very big files by acessing *chunks* of that file to proceed. I would say that, may be, every video editing software uses this technology. No other way to do.